# Importing from blender to unreal visual problems

Tags: import, blender, unreal-engine4

Imported blender objects have disappearing parts when viewed from different angles. Even chat GPT didn’t help

I made a mesh in blender and it looked fine, but when I imported into unreal engine parts of the mesh disappear as I move around and change the angle I’m viewing the mesh from.